# Toyota Fortuner OBD2 protocol

Tags: toyota, obd-ii

I used an ELM 327 and Torque app in one of my friend's Toyota Fortuner (2012 model), but didn't get correct data. Rpm was nil, Air intake temperature was negative, Load was constant at 6.66667%. After reading up a bit, it seems that Torque app is not able to detect the correct OBD2 protocol.
Can someone help me out with the correct protocol used by Fortuner, why is this problem happening, any solution to this problem.

P.S.: Can someone please link me to a website where I can get OBD2 protocol followed by **all** cars (till 2015 models). I couldn't find Fortuner protocol anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

It would make sense that the app isn't able to read ECU data correctly.

[This website](http://www.outilsobdfacile.com/vehicle-list-compatible-obd2/toyota) seems to do a decent job of identifying which protocol to use in which vehicle.

While it doesn't list the Fortuner, a bunch of 2012 vehicles including Camry, Land Cruiser and Yaris are listed as using `CAN 11-bit 500 KBaud`, which would suggest to me that the Fortuner uses the same.